Mentor for Marie-Curie postdoctoral fellowship
I'm interested in applying for a Marie Curie postdoctoral fellowship and would like to choose a host institute in the UK. If I choose a supervisor who is a senior researcher, would it impact my application compared to choosing a senior professor? Actually, I'm interested in the research work of a senior researcher at the university.

Can you more specifically define "senior researcher"? That's not a standardised title, and I've seen places where that could imply anything from a few years postdoc experience up to an established group leader.

@StephenMcMahon, yes senior researcher means the one who has a few years Postdoc positions, and currently a research fellow, has experience Upto an established group leader.

I'm going to slightly disagree with the other answer by BioBrains, conditional on exactly how experienced the "senior researcher" is.
The proposed supervisor's experience in supervision is one of the criteria on which the proposal is evaluated on according to the evaluation guidelines:

Scientific supervision arrangements should clearly define that the  proposed supervisors have sufficient expertise in supervising  researchers at postdoctoral level. Supervisors should have the time, knowledge, experience, expertise and commitment to be able to offer the appropriate support to the researcher and provide for the necessary progress, review and feedback procedures/ mechanisms.

So, if the "senior researcher" doesn't have any post doc supervision experience of their own, that is a clear negative. It's not insurmountable, and can be mitigated by e.g. good support structures and support from other experienced researchers, but it's something you should definitely be aware of.

I would add that a MCF is by scope a top end postdoc fellowship. If you are able to get that, then by definition it takes some fairly senior person to be able to teach you anything. At that stage, another postdoc can be a great collaborator but not a supervisor.

No - it won't. The Marie Curie IF is very much dependent on the proposal and within that the science and the mentoring description. Reputation matters less, which is a good thing and great to also make more junior group leaders more competitive in getting a postdoc with a fellow ship.
